# Trying to implement a type converter for CsvHelper has no effect

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to globally register a CsvHelper type converter that handles the value `NULL` for a `decimal?`, but when I do the registration is ignored and the converter is not invoked.  Not sure what else to do.

My converter:

```
public class NullDecimalConverter : DecimalConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData mapData)
    {
        if (text == "NULL") return null;
        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, mapData);
    }
}
```

My class and mapping are as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public decimal? Score{ get; set; }      
}

public class ScoreMapping : ClassMap<Model>
{
    public ScoreMapping()
    {
        Map(m => m.Score).Name("sub_score");
    }
}
```

And to set it up

```
csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<ScoreMapping>();
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new NullDecimalConverter());
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();
```

But the library doesn't do it

```
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException : The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: 'NULL'
    MemberType: System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.NullableConverter'
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7YFE8).

---

As a workaround, it seems I can  add the TypeConverter on each type, but this is clunky, is there a proper way to register the type converter globally?

```
Map(m => m.Score).Name("sub_score").TypeConverter<NullDecimalConverter>();
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Maybe you want `csvReader.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal?>(new NullDecimalConverter());`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with CsvHelper version 27.0.0.0, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3Hftf.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: @dbc thanks - Thank you, I've modified the fiddle to show it breaking... https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7YFE8 - by just adding a mapping class. I eventually figured out if we reverse the order of registering the class mapping to after the type converter, this fixes it. But is it worth a bug report? I guess there's an unknown requirement on order of execution there.

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  Might just be a [documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/) issue?  This seems like the sort of situation where a self-answer might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was order of execution...
`AddConverter` must be called before `RegisterClassMap` else the converter will not be registered.

I reckon I should raise this as a bug because relying on order is probably something to avoid, especially in a library where this could easily be overlooked.

```
    // fails because class map is registered first
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ScoreMapping>();
    csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new NullDecimalConverter());

    // works because TypeConverter is added first
    csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new NullDecimalConverter());
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ScoreMapping>();
```